# Making Implicit OAuth2.0 flow through springfox

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, azure-active-directory, springfox

I am trying to add authentication in the swagger. I am using springfox for using swagger.
How can i add implicit Oauth2 in the swagger.

Comment: This might help: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#securing-swagger-ui

Comment: Adn this: https://github.com/springfox/springfox-oath2-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/myprojects/sample/oauth/config/SwaggerConfig.java